# Inheritance TreeNode

Tags: c#, .net-core, treeview

I want to create my TreeNode - TreeINode. I inherit TreeNode in TreeINode. The error gets out:

> Error CS7069 The link to the type "MarshalByRefObject" requires its definition in "mscorlib", but it could not be found.

Found a solution to the error: add to the links System.Data.dll
Further the error takes off:

> Error mismatch between the processor architecture of the "MSIL" project, which is being assembled, and the processor architecture of the "System.Data" link, "AMD64". This inconsistency can lead to runtime errors. It is recommended that you change the target processor architecture for a project using the Configuration Manager to match the processor architectures for the project and references, or use link dependency with the processor architecture that is appropriate for the target processor architecture of the project.

Target platforms:
.NET Framework 4.6
ASP.NET Core 1.0
Windows Universal 10.0
The project itself is a class library.

When you hover the cursor on the TreeNode window pops up:

> Module 'mscorlib, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089' should be referenced

Comment: Please share the code snippet.

Comment: I'm confused, do you still have a problem?

Comment: @Guy yes. "Error CS7069 The link to the type "MarshalByRefObject" requires its definition in "mscorlib", but it could not be found."

Comment: @Sham I just inherit TreyNoda to my class and get an error.